# How can I refresh my ListView using BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, notifydatasetchanged

I tried refresh my listview using notifyDataSetChanged() but this is marked on red. I use ListView like extended Adapter so notifyDataSetChaned it should work but is otherwise.

Below is my declaration ListView and ArrayList.

```
ListView listview;
ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I set up my list in this way:

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listview.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(this, myList));
```

I use also setOnScrollListener and I want that my listview it refresh when SROLL_STATE = 0;

```
    listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int position = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            SCROLL_STATE = position;

            if (SCROLL_STATE == 0) {
                listview.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Here is a problem, because it's not work
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you should check your imported package name is your extended listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Adapter object,
MyBaseAdapter adapter=new MyBaseAdapter(this, myList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have a that log: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Comment: Great! this log I have because I create a stack activity and somewhere is a wrong. When I open one activity and use your solution all is the best. Please tell, how can I refresh listview from IntentService? I created public static MyBaseAdapter mListAdapter and I try invoke to the method from IntentService but my app is closed.

Answer (score 2):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is a method of the **BaseAdapter** class and ***not*** the **ListView** class. Hence, it is logically and syntactically incorrect to call `listView.notifyDatasSetChanged();`.

Replace this line with

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

All the best :)

Comment: My BaseAdapter is extends of public class MyBaseAdapter "public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {" I try invoke notifyDataSetChanged() from other activity. Your example not resolve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: I get that. The notifyDataSetChanged() is a public method of that class. The line that I suggested is to first get the adapter associated with the listView and then call the notifyDataSetChanged() method to redraw the listview if there any changes to the underlying data(any insertions or removals from the data).

Comment: I can not use this method. I'll explain what's going on. The package is created from a public JSONArray. In this array is more a JSONObject and it are working perfectly. In a background using IntentService with HttpRequest are downloads new data if exists. When a new data is downloaded then the global JSONAarray is changed but my listview not. Now I must refresh listview without create a new activity.

Comment: I am not sure why there is a problem. Anyway, maybe this will help : http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html

Comment: SeaDog - I'm not understanding how your explanation changes the relevance of Narayan Acharya's answer.  ListView simply doesn't provide the method "notifyDataSetChanged"... but getAdapter() does.

Comment: I don't know how use this method in my code. When I put listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); in onScrollStateChanged all the time notifyDataSetChanged is on red marked. I understand notifyDataSetChanged is method of Adapter. I have no idea.

Comment: Additionally, how can I update listview from other activity or better IntentService?

Comment: Read up on BroadcastReceivers. You will have to register a receiver with your Activity. From your IntentService you can send a Broadcast. When you send a Broadcast all the registered receivers will get notified. When notified, update your Activity. This might help : http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/ Also if the answer satisfied your query please select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I use WakefullBroadcastReceiver to check in period 3 seconds if data has changed on server and here is just a problem, because if my data has changed, how can I refresh listview? I try in this way myList.clear(); and then again create a new list but it is good idea?

Comment: That certainly is not a good idea. Too much work redrawing the view. Did notifyDataSetChanged() method not work for you?

Comment: I want use this method but I don't know how. I'm reading about that but I don't know  where it put in my code. Additionally you are writing that this is method of Adapter and I use Activity where is my listview and BaseAdapter where is created this view. I'm new in android.

Comment: You must know that my data come from a global JSONArray and I not put/remove their the hand

Comment: OK, I added private MyBaseAdapter mListAdapter; I can refresh my listview but how can I refresh from IntentService? I created new method in activity and there I put notifyDataSetChanged() with other code. In intentservice I create object this Activity and I try run my new method which should refresh listview but something is wrong and my app is closed.

Comment: Do not create instance of Activity in the IntentService. Communication between the IntentService and Activity is done using BroadcastReceiver. Please see simple samples of sending broadcast from your Service and receiving the same in your Activity.